# problem with conditional probability and independence

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem, independence

Let $P(E) = 0.4$ and $P(F) = 0.7$, with $E$ and $F$ independent. How to calculate
 $P(((F \cup E^c)\cap(F^c \cup E)) \mid (E^c \cap F))$?

Comment: Can you simplify $(F \cup E^c)\cap(F^c \cup E)$ a little?

Comment: using venn diagram, i get E∪F @DilipSarwate

Comment: no i meant E ∩ F

Comment: Both simplifications $E\cup F$ and $E\cap F$ are not correct. Look again at your Venn diagram.  If you also mark on it the set $E^c \cap F$, you might discover the final answer more quickly. In fact, the final answer does not depend at all on the probabilities of $E$ and $F$ or the independence or dependence of $E$ and $F$, and this causes me to ask: Are you _sure_ that you have written down the question correctly? There have been several edits (some by me), and maybe the question as it reads right now is not what was actually asked.

Comment: @DilipSarwate the question is not from textbook or any other sites. my professor gave this problem at the end of a lecture by say 'try this' so i guess he gave us a probability that doesnt make sense?

Comment: but if you simplify (F∪Ec)∩(Fc∪E) dont you get E n F??

Comment: "but if you simplify $(F\cup E^c)\cap((F^c\cup E)$, don't you get $E\cap F$??" Well, I don't and neither does Graham Kemp. See the very first line of his answer. Your professor didn't give you probabilities that make no sense; he gave you probabilities that are not _needed_ to get the answer that the conditional probability asked for has value $0$ (except possibly for ensuring that $P(E^c\cap F) > 0$ so that the conditional probability asked for is properly defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By distribution $(F\cup E^{\small\complement})\cap(F^{\small\complement}\cup E) = (F\cap E)\cup(E^{\small\complement}\cap F^{\small\complement})$

So clearly... $\mathsf P\big((F\cup E^{\small\complement})\cap(F^{\small\complement}\cup E) \;\big|\; (E^{\small\complement}\cap F)\big)
\\ = \mathsf P\big((F\cap E)\cup(E^{\small\complement}\cap F^{\small\complement}) \;\big|\; (E^{\small\complement}\cap F)\big)
\\ \vdots
\\ = \boxed{\color{white}{0}\qquad}?$

> Hint: disjoint sets. Where?

Comment: The answer does not depend on the values of $P(E)$ and $P(F)$ and whether or not $E$ and $F$ are independent, and I wonder if the current version of the question is different from the one actually asked in the OP's homework or textbook.